# Flutter: How to open Camera for both image and video

Tags: flutter, camera

I want to open the `camera`, and then either a photo or a video. I don't want to have to specify whether I will be taking a photo or video before the camera opens.

Are there any packages that allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this package :
[flutter_better_camera](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_better_camera)